# D3 having problems sorting a data set

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I read in the following data set Id like it to be reversed so 2014 is first

year,a,b,c,d,e
2017,.496488,.084909,1.354420,.133384,.405901
2016,.908474,.129965,2.371645,.184770,.708384
2015,.806038,.079820,2.129474,.184854,.681016
2014,.913967,.130637,2.113391,.152658,.749717

```
var dataFile = ".\\temp\\yeardata.csv";
d3.csv(dataFile, type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

//data.sort(function(a, b) { return  b.year; });
//data.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.ascending(a[0], b[0]); })
```

I tried using these 2 lines to sort by year with no luck any ideas what i am doing wrong? 
    //data.sort(function(a, b) { return  b.year; });
    //data.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.ascending(a[0], b[0]); })

to be more specific these don't cause errors just my graph doesn't change it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to pass the years to `d3.ascending`. Try using something like:

```
data.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.ascending(a.year, b.year); })
```